# Java threads waiting on Mysql connections, but Mysql shows no evidence of this

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc, jersey-2.0

We've been experiencing a prod issue that requires restarting our tomcat servers to fix.  We can reproduce this with a performance test, but we're not exactly sure the series of events required to reproduce it.  It just seems if we throw enough traffic at a tomcat instance, it eventually has the following problem:

Tomcat has 200 threads available, but all 200 of them are doing this:

```
"http-nio-8080-exec-1" #41 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7264a5b800 nid=0xdf9 runnable [0x00007f71e39fd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:101)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:144)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:174)
    - locked <0x000000008b9bbb60> (a com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3008)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:567)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1016)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2188)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2035)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2019)
    - locked <0x000000008b9bbc88> (a com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:776)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor69.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MultiHostConnectionProxy.createConnectionForHost(MultiHostConnectionProxy.java:346)
    - eliminated <0x000000008b9bc188> (a com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancedConnectionProxy)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancedConnectionProxy.createConnectionForHost(LoadBalancedConnectionProxy.java:372)
    - eliminated <0x000000008b9bc188> (a com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancedConnectionProxy)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.RandomBalanceStrategy.pickConnection(RandomBalanceStrategy.java:73)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancedConnectionProxy.pickNewConnection(LoadBalancedConnectionProxy.java:317)
    - locked <0x000000008b9bc188> (a com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancedConnectionProxy)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancedConnectionProxy.<init>(LoadBalancedConnectionProxy.java:229)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancedConnectionProxy.createProxyInstance(LoadBalancedConnectionProxy.java:105)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connectLoadBalanced(NonRegisteringDriver.java:374)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:314)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationConnectionProxy.initializeMasterConnection(ReplicationConnectionProxy.java:415)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationConnectionProxy.<init>(ReplicationConnectionProxy.java:182)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationConnectionProxy.createProxyInstance(ReplicationConnectionProxy.java:85)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connectReplicationConnection(NonRegisteringDriver.java:459)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringReplicationDriver.connect(NonRegisteringReplicationDriver.java:46)
    at com.myapp.rest.JSONService.setUpConnection(JSONService.java:1278) ******************************************************************************
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor120.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$$Lambda$127/439202272.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:243)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1489)
    - locked <0x000000008a974068> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I know that's a big wall of text, but you can find our code by searching for `******************************************************************************` in that stack trace.

Since all available threads are waiting to grab a connection, tomcat becomes unresponsive.  When the tomcat gets locked up like this, there are no connections on the mysql master (although I haven't checked the slaves).  So it appears like the Java code is waiting for a connection from the database and the database has no record of Java trying to connect to it.

This database has 7k available connections and through New Relic we can see that there are never more than 3k made.  So it's not an issue of the DB being out of connections.

Here is the code used to make the connection:

```
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver");
    final String JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING = System.getProperty("JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING");
    final String DB_USER_STRING = System.getProperty("DB_USER_STRING");
    final String DB_PASSWORD_STRING = System.getProperty("DB_PASSWORD_STRING");

    ReplicationDriver driver = new ReplicationDriver();

    Properties props = new Properties();

    // We want this for failover on the slaves
    props.put("autoReconnect", "true");

    // We want to load balance between the slaves
    props.put("roundRobinLoadBalance", "true");

    props.put("user", DB_USER_STRING);
    props.put("password", DB_PASSWORD_STRING);
    props.put("useLocalSessionState", "true");
    props.put("useLocalTransactionState", "true");
    props.put("connectTimeout", System.getProperty("MYSQL_CLIENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MS"));
    props.put("socketTimeout", System.getProperty("MYSQL_CLIENT_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS"));

    if(use_utf8)
    {
        props.put("useUnicode", "yes");
        props.put("characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
    }

    connect = driver.connect(JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING, props);  //all threads block on this line
    connect.setReadOnly(false);
```

As a workaround, we added the lines for MYSQL_CLIENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MS and MYSQL_CLIENT_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS.  Setting these prevents the machines from getting locked up, but we haven't really solved the underlying issue.    I'd like to fix the underlying issue: **Why is the Java code waiting for connections to the database?**

We are using MySQL on RDS, version 5.6.10.

I'm using Tomcat 8, and JDK 8, Jersey 2.26, and

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.45</version>
    </dependency>
```

It's probably worth noting I'm connecting to this database with this jdbc url prefix: `jdbc:mysql:replication://`.  Also, this only seems to happen on RDS, not locally.  A difference between the two environments is RDS has masters and slaves, locally it does not.

Comment: What kind of Mysql operations are done under your Tomcat traffic? Only select operations? Is it possible a deadlock is happening when your concurrent UPDATE/DELETE/SELECT requests are sent to Mysql server?  If there is a deadlock, your threads would act like you described above.

Comment: @ftb we are doing all sorts of CRUD operations.  But, I'm not sure if I agree with your statement because the stacktrace always shows it waiting for a connection, not for a CRUD operation.  Why would it stall there due to a DB deadlock?  Keep in mind that the db has 7k connections to give and each tomcat only uses 200.

Comment: Do a heap dump and see what threads are deadlocked in the JVM.  Ask the database to give you information about how many connections are available at a given moment.

Comment: @duffymo I already have that information in my question.  There are no threads that are marked as 'deadlocked'.  There are 1000s of available connections for the database.

Comment: @duffymo actually, maybe nm.  Did you mean a heap dump or a thread dump?  I've pasted the thread dump.

Comment: Sure looks like you made a JDBC connection to me.  You're reading from the socket, but nothing is being sent.  What is the database server doing?

Comment: @duffymo according to mysql (we checked with `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`), this instance has no connections to mysql.  Not sure if that's the answer to the question you're asking.

Comment: "   - locked <0x000000008b9bbb60> (a com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream)" - this makes me thing Java JDBD got a connection.  Maybe that's the issue - why does MySQL not agree?

Comment: @DanielKaplan Facing the same issue, could you share some pointers on how you proceeded to fix it?

Comment: @yolob21 this may not help much, but we couldn't make sense of the code and switched it to use a connection pool.  When we did that, it didn't have this problem.

Comment: any specific library?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a database connection pool, it would suggest that the pool has been exhausted, probably because connections are not being closed and returned to the pool properly.

It's not clear from your post how you've designed your application.

1. Did you assume one connection per user, persisting throughout the session?
2. Do you check out, use, close, and return a connection in the narrowest method scope possible?
3. Are you using Spring?

Comment: 1. We are assuming one connection per request.  The connection is closed at the end of every request.  2. I don't believe so.  We open the connection on the beginning of every request and then close it at the end of every request. 3. No, we are using Jersey 2.26.  We are not using a connection pool at all.

Comment: I’d recommend using a pool, configured appropriately.

Comment: We tried using a pool and that made performance worse, for some reason.  Regardless, even without a pool, I don't think these symptoms should be happening.